# Using ADB from Python

Tags: android, python, adb

I want to run adb commands from python and I've found google's own library for that but it doesn't work. 
https://github.com/google/python-adb


This Is the Code I've used: (It's from the example)

```
import os.path as op

from adb import adb_commands
from adb import sign_m2crypto

signer = sign_m2crypto.M2CryptoSigner(
    op.expanduser('~/.android/adbkey'))

device = adb_commands.AdbCommands.ConnectDevice(rsa_keys=[signer])
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/elichai2/PycharmProjects/Test/python_adb.py", line 9, in <module>
    device = adb_commands.AdbCommands.ConnectDevice(rsa_keys=[signer])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adb/adb_commands.py", line 76, in ConnectDevice
    return cls.Connect(handle, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adb/adb_commands.py", line 99, in Connect
    device_state = cls.protocol_handler.Connect(usb, banner=banner, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adb/adb_protocol.py", line 277, in Connect
    cmd, arg0, arg1, banner = cls.Read(usb, ['CNXN', 'AUTH'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adb/adb_protocol.py", line 235, in Read
    actual_checksum = cls.CalculateChecksum(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/adb/adb_protocol.py", line 187, in CalculateChecksum
    return sum(map(ord, data)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Same here... I just created issue on github page: https://github.com/google/python-adb

Answer (score 2):

You can try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)'s [adbclient.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/src/com/dtmilano/android/adb/adbclient.py) which is an ADB client implemented in python.

This is a [simple example](http://dtmilano.blogspot.ca/2014/03/adbclient-under-hood-of.html) of how to use `AdbClient` alone without `AndroidViewClient`.

Comment: I'll need to use their whole project because they got lots of inside dependencies (and they depend on more files inside the project)

Comment: `s/their/your/` - Diego is the author of `AVC`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to install these dependencies?
from here [GIthub]: https://github.com/google/python-adb

Comment: It is recommended to include the list in the answer rather than referring with a link

Answer (score 1):

A more recently maintained option might be https://github.com/JeffLIrion/adb_shell. The [Google python-adb](https://github.com/google/python-adb) package website refers to this one as a better alternative.